# how to get int from JTextField with a JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextfield

I'm trying to get an int from my JTextField with the click of my JButton but I can't figure out how to do so. I'm trying to get the int and set it to a variable so I can use it in my program further down.

Here is the code(this is the whole method):

```
    JFrame presets = new JFrame("Presets");
    presets.setVisible(true);
    presets.setSize(500, 500);

    JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(2,2));

    JPanel labelFields = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(2,2));
    labelFields.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Presets"));

    JPanel labels = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1,1,1));

    JPanel fields = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1,1,1));

    labels.add(new JLabel("Place values on Cat.2/Cat.3 at"));
    JTextField f1 = new JTextField(10);
    String text = f1.getText();
    int first = Integer.parseInt(text);
    labels.add(new JLabel("and place follow up value at"));
    fields.add(new JTextField(10));


    labelFields.add(labels, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    labelFields.add(fields, BorderLayout.EAST);

    JPanel guiCenter = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(2,2));

    JPanel submit = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));

    submit.add( new JButton("Submit") );
    guiCenter.add( submit, BorderLayout.NORTH );

    gui.add(labelFields, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    gui.add(guiCenter, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);
```

Comment: More details please? It's like shooting an arrow at a target you barely know exists in a dark room.

Comment: Not clear which data? in what form?

Comment: Start with [`JTextField#getText`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getText%28%29) and then take a look at [How to use text fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html) and [How to use formatted text fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) and [How to use spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html)

Comment: 1) Use a `JSpinner` in a `SpinnerNumberModel` as seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556). 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Noticing the latest edit:  Someone might be able to help with the addition of a code snippet, but I still recommend an SSCCE.

Comment: does this make things clear?

Comment: Did you even read the SSCCE document?

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
      String getText()

      Returns the text contained in this TextComponent.
```

So, convert your String to Integer as:

```
try {
    int integerValue = Integer.parseInt(jTextField.getText());
}
catch(NumberFormatException ex)
{
    System.out.println("Exception : "+ex);
}
```

Comment: how do I get my JButton to do this? Do I just use this code right underneath my JButton?

Comment: @ChildProdigy Take a look at [Creating a GUI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/), [How to use buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [How to write an action listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer That's why i am waiting.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I have tried nothing has worked that's why I have come to you guys for help

Comment: @ChildProdigy That's fine, but be prepared for some intense learning ;) - Take the time to read through the linked tutorials and when you have a particular issue with those, let us know.  We're happy to help, but you need to be prepared to work for it ;)

Answer (score 2):

if you want to get the f1 text when the submit pressed, use this code:

```
   .
   .
   .
    JPanel submit = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    JButton button = new JButton("Submit");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            int first = Integer.parseInt(f1.getText().trim());
        }
    });
    submit.add(button);
    guiCenter.add(submit, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      .
      .
      .
```

Comment: That works perfectly. If I was to do that for the second textfield I could use the same button listener, correct?

Comment: yes of course.
and you must define first and f1 before the method you are using, other wise you will get the error which asks you to make them final.

Comment: As a quick note, you might want to use `f1.getText().trim()` to remove any random whitespace that could be at the start or end of the input `String`

Answer (score 2):

Probably you want the entered data as `int`. write it in the button action

```
JButton button = new JButton("Submit");
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    try {
      int myInt=Integer.parseInt(jtextfield.getText());
      System.out.println("Integer is: "+myInt);
      //do some stuff
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
      System.out.println("Not a number");
      //do you want
   }
  }
});
```

Remember `Integer.parseInt` throws `NumberFormatException` which must be caught. see [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29)